# RAR command-line: how to include a directory (recursively) but with another name in the archive?

Tags: windows, command-line, compression, rar

I have read [RAR a folder without persisting the full path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9684705/rar-a-folder-without-persisting-the-full-path)
 which helps about the RAR `-ep1` switch but I still have the following problem:

I want to add the directory `D:\Temp\FolderA` and its subdirectories/files to a RAR archive:

```
D:\Temp\FolderA\A1
D:\Temp\FolderA\B2
D:\Temp\FolderA\C3\D4\E5.txt
```

... but with a custom name in the archive instead of `FolderA`. Inside the RAR archive, it should look like this:

```
BaseFolder\SubDir\OtherName\A1
BaseFolder\SubDir\OtherName\B2
BaseFolder\SubDir\OtherName\C3\D4\E5.txt
```

I tried:

```
rar a -r test.rar D:\Temp\FolderA
```

but obviously the name `FolderA` appears in the RAR package, which I don't want.

**How is it possible with RAR?**

Note: If possible, I'd like to avoid to temporary rename `D:\Temp\FolderA` into `D:\Temp\BaseFolder\SubDir\OtherName`, and avoid to create temporary symlinks.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution in the meantime with the switch `-ap"New path"` combined with `-ep1`:

```
rar a -r test.rar -ep1 -ap"BaseFolder\SubDir\OtherName\" "D:\Temp\FolderA\*"
```

Indeed the [RAR command-line manual](https://ss64.com/bash/rar.html) states:

> ```
> -ap    Set path inside archive. This path is *merged* to file names when
>        adding  files to an archive [...]
> ```